# wkhtmltopdf with full page background image

Tags: image, background, header, wkhtmltopdf

I've got wkhtmltopdf working with a header and footer image, and everything spaced well.  But the task is to use a full page background image which looks like a sort of frame, with the page text in the center.  I thought I could place this in the header, but it doesn't work - maybe the use of a full page header doesn't make sense here.

(These are multi-page documents, which could be of any length).

Any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 10):

I have a similar problem, this is what I understood so far:

- It's not possible to center the text vertically on the page simply via CSS+wkhtmltopdf on a multi-page document (might find some complex javascript stuff, but it wasn't worth in my case);
- since **wkhtmltopdf** uses webkit, and webkit doesn't support *@page* rules, it's not possible to define a "paged" background via CSS

Hence what? You will need a little hack and use **pdftk**

**1.** In your CSS define:

```
body {
    background: white;
}
```

(if you have a body tag in your header.html and footer.html make sure that rule applies to them as well)

**2.** Create a one-page pdf with your background image (using the same page size as your final pdf)

**3.** Install [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/) and from command line:

```
$ pdftk yourfile.pdf background background.pdf output yourfile_b.pdf
```

**4.** Enjoy :)

Comment: This is one clever, albeit cumbersome workaround. Let's hope they upgrade to the nightly for Webkit soon!

Comment: This solution is also useful to keep high quality of background image/content. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution BASED on webkit, like HTM2PDF - you'll be able to add a feature called 'stationary' where you can integrate any image as a full page background.

more info at the documentation [from the API page](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-api)